# VS2017 publish does not stop at first error

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, publish

I have an asp.net core application that I need to publish on IIS. I am using the visual studio publishing mechanism. However every time that I am trying to publish the first time I am getting errors for not been able to delete the files.
Since I am publishing more file the publishing mechanism does not stop at the first error, but it tries to delete the other file also.

Is there a way to tell visual studio to stop at the first error and not continue further.

Answer (score 1):

Update to Visual Studio 2019 , it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> However every time that I am trying to publish the first time I am getting errors for not been able to delete the files.

As far as I know, files in the deployment folder are locked when the site/app is running.

To fix the above issue, you can try to stop the site/app on IIS server first, then do deployment.

Comment: Since the second time works, does this mean that the publish mechanism has done this? But why only on the second time I publish?

Comment: To troubleshoot the issue, you can try to check which process block that specific file(s) using Process Monitor.

Comment: The publishing is done on server so I can not use Process Monitor. Also I know that there are user connected to the IIS site while I publish so I assume because of their connection I can not publish. But this is not my problem. My problem is that I publish more than 100 files and I would like for the publish to fail at first file not to try to remove all 100 files cause it takes time.